# como puedo agregar varios botones con una misma funcion

Tags: html, css

quisiera saber como puedo agregar varios botones y que cada uno al darle click tenga una función de (input= tipe" file") estoy empezando en todo esto de programacion pero no encuntro una respuesta, esto es lo unico que tengo:

Comment: Hola te faltó agregar tu código

Comment: Como agregar botones que tengan la misma funcion ?? `<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¡Hola! Lo que tu pregunta me da a entender es que quieres que un botón aparezca x número de veces en una página sin tener que hacer colocamiento  manual, esto lo puedes hacer con bucles en Javascript, pero debes de conocer el número de iteraciones (ciclos) que se realizará el bucle, que es el equivalente a cuantos botones habrá, esto lo puedes obtener en tu aplicación con procesamiento, un número predefinido por ti o valores aleatorios.

Sería algo así:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="seccion-botones">
      <!-- Contenido del div -->
  </div>
  <script>
    let div = document.querySelector("#seccion-botones"); // Declara el objeto del elemento en el DOM.
    for(let i = 0; i !== 5; i++) { // Inicializa el bucle, 5 es el número de iteraciones
      let boton = document.createElement("input"); // Declara el nuevo botón por cada iteración
      boton.setAttribute("type", "submit"); // Declara que el elemento a insertar es un botón
      div.appendChild(boton); // Inserta el elemento en el DOM
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```